# Change Specific Process in Windows 10 to High Priority?

Tags: java, c++, windows, process, io

Is there a way to do this in Java? Else, what is the best way to do it in another language; C++ with Windows API?

I just want to change one specific process for another running application to be High every time I run my program. Yes, I know I can do this with a windows shortcut, but I'd like to implement it in code, preferably Java.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about thread priorities, what problem specifically do you hope to address with this? Trying to help the system usually results in an overall pessimization.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `setPriority()` method in thread class
Check this [one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    // Your main code.
}
```

For c++ this Windows API call [setPriorityClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx) allows you to change your process priority.
**EDIT :**
If you want to change the program's priority in windows 10, check this [article](http://mywindowshub.com/set-cpu-priority-level-processes-windows-8-1/)

Comment: I want to change another program's windows 10 priority, not my own thread.

Comment: @HuangLee just for records consider accepting the solution if helped in any way